# NASM XOR signature (32bit)

Tags: nasm

I was searching for the signature of the NASM XOR operation, but could not find it in the manual.
What is the signature of NASM's XOR operation? As in, what registers combination/addressing modes are possible when doing `XOR X, Y`? Is it limited to certain registers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's defined by the instruction set (x86), not by NASM. These are the valid forms of XOR (taken from [Intel's Software Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech+64-32_manuals)):

```
Opcode           Instruction      Op/En  64-Bit Mode  Compat/Leg Mode  Description
34 ib            XOR AL, imm8     I      Valid        Valid            AL XOR imm8.
35 iw            XOR AX, imm16    I      Valid        Valid            AX XOR imm16.
35 id            XOR EAX, imm32   I      Valid        Valid            EAX XOR imm32.
REX.W + 35 id    XOR RAX, imm32   I      Valid        N.E.             RAX XOR imm32 (sign-extended).
80 /6 ib         XOR r/m8, imm8   MI     Valid        Valid            r/m8 XOR imm8.
REX + 80 /6 ib   XOR r/m8*, imm8  MI     Valid        N.E.             r/m8 XOR imm8.
81 /6 iw         XOR r/m16, imm16 MI     Valid        Valid            r/m16 XOR imm16.
81 /6 id         XOR r/m32, imm32 MI     Valid        Valid            r/m32 XOR imm32.
REX.W + 81 /6 id XOR r/m64, imm32 MI     Valid        N.E.             r/m64 XOR imm32 (sign-extended).
83 /6 ib         XOR r/m16, imm8  MI     Valid        Valid            r/m16 XOR imm8 (sign-extended).
83 /6 ib         XOR r/m32, imm8  MI     Valid        Valid            r/m32 XOR imm8 (sign-extended).
REX.W + 83 /6 ib XOR r/m64, imm8  MI     Valid        N.E.             r/m64 XOR imm8 (sign-extended).
30 /r            XOR r/m8, r8     MR     Valid        Valid            r/m8 XOR r8.
REX + 30 /r      XOR r/m8*, r8*   MR     Valid        N.E.             r/m8 XOR r8.
31 /r            XOR r/m16, r16   MR     Valid        Valid            r/m16 XOR r16.
31 /r            XOR r/m32, r32   MR     Valid        Valid            r/m32 XOR r32.
REX.W + 31 /r    XOR r/m64, r64   MR     Valid        N.E.             r/m64 XOR r64.
32 /r            XOR r8, r/m8     RM     Valid        Valid            r8 XOR r/m8.
REX + 32 /r      XOR r8*, r/m8*   RM     Valid        N.E.             r8 XOR r/m8.
33 /r            XOR r16, r/m16   RM     Valid        Valid            r16 XOR r/m16.
33 /r            XOR r32, r/m32   RM     Valid        Valid            r32 XOR r/m32.
REX.W + 33 /r    XOR r64, r/m64   RM     Valid        N.E.             r64 XOR r/m64.
```

`imm` means an immediate, like `5` or `13` (or a label). `r/m` means either a register or a memory operand (e.g. `al`, `bh`and `byte [foo]` would all match `r/m8`.